# Bootstrap Scrollspy with Multiple Navbars

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, scrollspy

[**Here is a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tZbyt/1/).

Due to a problem described [**in this question about creating a responsive nav menu**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904454/fixed-responsive-nav-switch-from-top-to-side-popout-with-single-dom-element), I need to have two identical nav elements, one that is visible for small screens and another for large.

However I'd like scrollspy to track and apply `.active` classes to both simultaneously. For simplicity's sake, lets say we have two identical navs like this one:

```
<div class="scrollspy navbar">
    <nav class="nav">
        <li><a href="#option1">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#option2">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#option3">Option 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#option4">Option 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#option5">Option 5</a></li>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And then the content:

```
<div class="content">
    <section id="option1">1</section>
    <section id="option2">2</section>
    <section id="option3">3</section>
    <section id="option4">4</section>
    <section id="option5">5</section>
</div>
```

And then call on scrollspy:

```
$(".wrapper").scrollspy({ target: ".scrollspy" });
```

You'll see in the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tZbyt/1/) that the active class gets messed up and flickers back and forth on both navs. If you remove the `scrollspy` class from one of the navs, however, the other one works fine. Is this fixable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fix my friend. It is a bit mouthful, so if anyone have a more straightforward fix please go ahead. In the mean time this'll get it fixed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".wrapper").scrollspy({ target: ".scrollspy" });

    var scollSpy2ActiveLI = "";

    $('.wrapper').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
        if (scollSpy2ActiveLI != "") {
            scollSpy2ActiveLI.removeClass('active');            
        }        
        var activeTab = $('.scrollspy li.active a').attr('href');
        scollSpy2ActiveLI = $('.scrollspy2 li a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').parent();
        scollSpy2ActiveLI.addClass('active');
    })

    $('.wrapper').trigger('activate.bs.scrollspy');
});
```

Notice I am using `.scrollspy2` for your second nav.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jofrysutanto/MUpz5/1/

Answer (score 2):

This solution didn't work for me as I had 2 navs which were not identical and didn't have the same anchor links inside. (an active link in .scrollspy1 didn't necessarily had the corresponding twin in .scrollspy2)

However, a simple:

```
$(".wrapper").scrollspy({ target: ".scrollspy, .scrollspy2" });
```

was enough to fixe the flickering problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply an empty target, all navs work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23937735

Just tested it myself. A surprising solution.

Answer (score 0):

use id instead of classes.

```
$(".wrapper").scrollspy({ target: "#scrollspy" });
```